# is the Lyapunov exponent a continuous function of the invariant measure w.r.t weak-* topology?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

I hope for some relerant results for the following question:
Is the lyapunov exponent continuous with respect to the measure?
Assume $M$ is a manifold, $f$ is a diffeomorphism on $M$, $m$ is an invariant measure. Then we have the Lyapunov exponent. Fix $M$ and $f$,is the largest Lyapunov exponent continuous with respect to the weak-* topolpgy on the measure? Do we have any result regarding the linear cocycle?

Comment: En effet! now fiexd...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the recent [survey by Viana](http://w3.impa.br/~viana/out/CS.pdf)

Comment: thank you very much